# How L = {a^n b^m | n,m>=1, n != 3m} is not regular?

Tags: automata, dfa

I'm struggling with the understanding of this problem.
Anyone any ideas?

Edit:
It was ...n,m<1..., however my question is ...n,m>=1...

Comment: n,m >= 1. not <=. Right?

Comment: You're right, I misspelled it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n and m are less than or equal to 1, then this language is in fact regular since it is the finite language {a, b, ab}. If, instead, you meant n and m are greater than or equal to 1, then the analysis becomes more difficult.

Assuming n and m are greater than or equal to 1, the language is infinite, and may or may not be regular. I have a feeling this language is going to be hard or impossible to prove non-regular using the pumping lemma for regular languages. There are two easier methods of proof available here: the Myhill-Nerode theorem and closure properties of regular languages.

To prove the language is non-regular using Myhill-Nerode, we need to identify an infinite sequence of strings which are all distinguishable with respect to our language. Two strings are distinguishable with respect to our language if they have different sets of strings that can be concatenated onto them to get to a string in our language. Consider the strings aaa, aaaaaa, …, a^3k, … . The shortest strings that cannot be concatenated to these to get strings in our language are b, bb, …, b^k, … . This means that every string a^3k is distinguishable with respect to our language; the sets of strings that can be concatenated to our strings depend on the parameter k. This shows that there are infinitely many equivalence classes under the indistinguishability relation with respect to our language. This means a minimal DFA for our language would have infinitely many states, a contradiction.

To prove the language is non-regular using closure properties, consider these languages:

```
L = {a^n b^m | n, m >= 1, n != 3m}
R = {a^n b^m | n, m >= 1, n = 3m}
S = {a^n b^m | n, m >= 1}
```

First, note that R is nonregular (the proof of this is simple using the pumping lemma) and that S is regular (this is the regular language aa*bb*).

Next, note that S \ L = R (here, \ indicates set difference).

However, this is a contradiction, since we assumed L is regular, we know S is regular, and we know regular languages are closed under set difference (we can construct a DFA for the difference of two regular languages using the Cartesian Product Machine construction). The difference of two regular languages cannot be the nonregular language R, so we have proved by contradiction that L must be nonregular.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to show nonregularity using closure properties.

Intuitively, we’d expect the language {a<sup>3n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n ∈ N} to be nonregular, since it’s essentially the canonical “n copies of a, then n copies of b” language stretched out a bit. If you’re comfortable with the idea that this language is not regular, great! If not, you can write a short proof of this using either the Myhill-Nerode theorem or the pumping lemma.

With that in mind, the language L = { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>m</sup> | n ≠ 3n } is very closely related to the one given above. It kinda sorta feels like it’s the “opposite“ of the above language, in fact. So let’s form the complement L’ of all strings that don’t appear in L. That would be all strings of the form a<sup>3n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>, plus all strings that didn’t match a*b*. And hey! If L is regular, then so is L’.

Since L’ has some strings in it that we don’t want, let’s intersect it with a*b* to just get the strings we want. Intersecting a regular language with a regular language gives back a regular language, which means that L’ ∩ a*b* is regular if L’ is. But that language is the one we saw above, which we know isn’t regular! That means that L isn’t either, and we’re done!